# ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate

Quisiera consultar si alguien tiene experiencia en hibernate. Por qué teóricamente esto hasta hace dos días estaba funcionando correctamente. (teóricamente por qué estaba desarrollando e hice una sola prueba, la cual guardó los datos correctamente y luego no probe hasta ahora). Ahora cuando quiero testear para poder poner este pedazo del código en producción me salta el error citado más abajo.

Dejo los mapeos de donde se produce el error y si es necesario cargaré todas las entidades completas para poder ver que sucede.

Por si algo llega a servir de ayuda estoy trabajando con jboss tools y hibernate 5.2.3 (si no me equivoco esa es la versión de la librería que poseo), cualquier comentario para ayudar se agradece.

```
//tabla Turnos
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "paciente", nullable = false)
public Paciente getPaciente() {
    return this.paciente;
}

public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
    this.paciente = paciente;
}


//tabla Paciente
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "paciente")
public Set<Turnos> getTurnoses() {
    return this.turnoses;
}

public void setTurnoses(Set<Turnos> turnoses) {
    this.turnoses = turnoses;
}
```

XML Turnos

```
    <many-to-one name="paciente" class="com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Paciente" fetch="select">
        <column name="paciente" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

XML Paciente

```
   <set name="turnoses" table="turnos" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="paciente" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Turnos" />
    </set>
```

//evento guardar turno

```
public static int NuevoTurno(Integer DNI, String fecha, String especialista, String horario) throws IOException {
    SessionFactory factory;
    int hecho = 0;
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        Log.CreaLog(he.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Turnos turno = new Turnos();
        List<Paciente> paciente = GestorPacientes.ConsultaInexistencia(DNI);
        //al paciente ya lo traigo en una lista, por que comparto con otras pantallas el mismo evento
        Estados estado = GestorEstados.ConsultarEstado(1);
        turno.setPaciente(paciente.get(0));
        turno.setFechaTurno(fecha);
        turno.setEspecialista(especialista);
        turno.setEstados(estado);
        turno.setHoraTurno(horario);

        try {
            session.save(turno);
            hecho = 1;
            Log.CreaLog("Turno Ingresado con Exito");
            return hecho;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.CreaLog(e.getMessage().toString());
            hecho = 0;
            return hecho;
        }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            hecho = 0;
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return hecho;
}
```

> ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`histocons`.`turnos`, CONSTRAINT `pacientes` FOREIGN KEY (`paciente`) REFERENCES `paciente` (`dni`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 0):

Y dónde está el `@Id` ?

Si no lo tiene asignado la tabla **turnos**, agrégelo; si lo tiene, me imagino que lo debe tener para que sea un `AUTO_INCREMENT` lo cual es:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.IDENTITY)
private long id;
```